# How to make spacemacs stop using treesitter mode

Tags: emacs, spacemacs, treesitter

I was curious about treesitter so I tried it.
I figured out that python-ts-mode has not much features so I want to go back.

But spacemacs now loads all .py files with python-ts-mode.
I want that it uses python instead.

I tried to do this, it does nothing.
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\.py[iw]?\'" . python-mode))

I dont remember how I changed it to python-ts-mode, I believe I was just running some commands from here https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/how-to-get-started-tree-sitter

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it for me
(setq auto-mode-alist (delete '("\.py[iw]?\'" . python-ts-mode) auto-mode-alist))